# C++ multi-thread program: Segementation fault with variables defined as class members

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to concurrent programming and learning it in C++. While learning `std::condition_variable`, I implemented a simple class `ManageTransaction` given below. Defining `_cv`, `_mutex`, and `_balance` as private members of the class causes a segmentation fault. Defining them globally doesn't cause it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <condition_variable>

std::condition_variable _cv;
std::mutex _mutex;
int _balance = 0;

class ManageTransaction {
public:
    void addMoney(int credit_value) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        std::cout << "t2, addMoney: _mutex is locked! \n";
        _balance += credit_value;
        std::cout << credit_value << " is added and the current balance is " << _balance << std::endl;
        _cv.notify_one();
        std::cout << "t2, addMoney: _mutex is unlocked! \n";
    }

    void withdrawMoney(int debit_value) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        std::cout << "t1, withdrawMoney: _mutex is locked! \n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); // simulate work
        _cv.wait(lock, [this] {return _balance == 0 ? false : true;});
        std::cout << "t1, withdrawMoney: wait is finished and _mutex is unlocked! \n";
        _balance -= debit_value;
        std::cout << "t1, withdrawMoney: " << debit_value << " is deducted and the current balance is " << _balance << std::endl;
    }

// private:
    // std::condition_variable _cv;
    // std::mutex _mutex;
    // int _balance = 0;
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<ManageTransaction> t;
    std::thread t1(&ManageTransaction::withdrawMoney, t, 500);
    std::thread t2(&ManageTransaction::addMoney, t, 500);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Q1. Why does the segmentation fault occur when the members are defined within the class?

Q2. Is there a way to avoid segmentation fault by defining the variables as members of the class?

Comment: Should avoid naming variables with `_`  or `__` prefix.

Comment: Where do you allocate the `ManageTransaction` managed by `t`?  The code shown will effectively end up dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: Hi @G.M., thank you for pointing out. This change fixed the problem: `std::shared_ptr<ManageTransaction> t(new ManageTransaction());`

Comment: Hi @Mansoor, thanks for the suggestion. Could you elaborate a bit more on the motivation to avoid it?

Comment: @stardust, these names are typical reserved for compiler and standard lib implementations, to avoid clashing with any of these symbols, you should avoiding name variables with underscore prefixes, postfix should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shared_ptr is uninitialised and will have a null value. Therefore as soon as the function attempts to access the private member data you'll get an access violation of sorts. Consider assigning your pointer using std::make_shared before trying to use it. Or better yet, do away with the shared_ptr; declare the variable on the stack and pass a reference instead.